# Unable to fetch coefficients from model summary

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have the below code chunk that I'm trying to execute. I'm calling `lm_model` function from a for loop for all the possible predictor variables in a table. However, when I try to extract the coefficients from the model summary I'm getting the following error: `Error: Index 1 must be a character or numeric vector`

Can you please let me know where I'm going wrong?

```
lm_model<- function(df1,i){
     model_summary <- list()
     fit_model[[i]] <- lm(paste("distance ~", i), data = df1)
     model_summary[[i]] <- summary( fit_model[[i]])
     return(model_summary)
  }

  for( i in names(FAA_final[,1:7])){
    summary_normal[i] <- lm_model(FAA_final, paste(i))
  }

  for(i in length(fit_normal)){
   coefficients[i] <-  map(fit_normal[[i]],coefficients)
  }
```

Comment: just do `local({attach(df1); setNames(lapply(df1,function(x)lm(distance~x)$coef),names(df1))})` local here ensures there is no data flow to your environment.

Comment: first you should save the model summary in a list! ie `summary_normal[i] <- lm_model(FAA_final, paste(i))` should have `[[]]`